# Prevent usb HDD Sleep mode?

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, suspend, samba

I'm having a problem with my computer running Ubuntu server 12.04, I have an external USB HDD plugged in for samba file sharing but after a few hours not using samba the USB HDD goes to sleep. When I try to use my samba share again I en up with an Input-Output error. How could I prevent the HDD from going into sleep (always spinning)?

**PS:** I mount my HDD to a folder in `/media/` at every boot using `fstab`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`hdparm -B255 /dev/sdX` will help as this disables the spindown.